# Check mat-checkbox within cypress test

Tags: angular, angular-material, cypress

I am trying to check `mat-checkbox` element with the cypress `check()` method and even if add `force` parameter. Example:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('changeEmailLayoutCheckbox', () =>
  cy
    .get(EMAIL_LAYOUT_CHECKBOX)
    .check({ force: true })
);
```

I am getting the following error

> cy.check() can only be called on :checkbox and :radio. Your subject is
>   a: <mat-checkbox

The message is quite clear but the problem is that I emit some event on `mat-checkbox` change, which set parameters to my request. I also have tried with `click()` but those not trigger mentioned event.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I think there is a check box that is a child of the mat-checkbox, inspect your html and you will see it I think, you need to select the check box within it. I did not put this as an answer, but I think I have ran into this before with Angular Material.

Comment: You are right I have to go deeper to find that input within mat-checkbox. You can put it as the answer I will mark it as good one ;)

Comment: will do. I appreciate the points

Comment: did it work out for you?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The check box is a child element of the mat-checkbox. You will need to select the inner child and click on that. I had to force it true to work. I will see if there is a better way to do that.

```js
describe('how to check mat-checkbox', () => {
  it('check the input', () => {       
    cy.visit('https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/overview');
      cy.get('#mat-checkbox-1-input').click({force:true});
      //**** OR ***********   
      cy.get('#mat-checkbox-1').find('input').click({force:true});    
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, it's resolved my problem. I had to look deeper inside of the mat-checkbox to find that input and on it fire a click event.

Answer (score 8):

**A simple solution following cypress's best practices**

Add a `data-cy` (best practices: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Selecting-Elements) or some other unique selector to the `mat-checkbox` element like so:

```
<mat-checkbox data-cy="some-unique-reference">...</mat-checkbox>
```

Since the actual `input` element (the checkbox itself) is a child of the mat-checkbox - in your spec file do:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="some-unique-reference"] input').should('be.checked');
cy.get('[data-cy="some-unique-reference"] input').click();
```

Comment: Already using the data-cy notation, just adding the `input` and also using `.click({force: true})` instead of `.check()` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

According to my experiments, the syntax can remain quite simple, without forcing, as long as the right element is chosen.

Sum up example:

```html
<div id="parent">
  <mat-checkbox ...></mat-checkbox>
  <!-- assuming there is no other input or mat-checkbox here -->
</div>
```

```js
cy.get('#parent mat-checkbox').click()       # interact
cy.get('#parent input').should('be.checked') # check state
```

### DOM Example

Here is how it looks like in the DOM, for an app:

- built with [ng build app --prod](https://angular.io/cli/build) - Angular 11
- served by nginx (probably doesn't matter here)

[image]

Comment: How can this work? `mat-checkbox` does not exist at runtime.

Comment: Well, I can't explain how or why, but I'm 100% sure it works, even when built with production flags, as in our CI pipeline. I have edited my answer with a snapshot of the DOM involved in our tests

Comment: Ok, my mistake.